# Jasmine unit test module is not defined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am currently busy with jasmine unit testing Angular.
I have put this unit test in test.js

```
describe('The countInput filter', function(){
    var $filter;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('countInputFilter');

        inject(function(_$filter_){
            $filter = _$filter_;
        });
    });

    it('Should not give an output when the length of the input is > 3', function(){

        var input = 'test';

        result = $filter('countInputFilter')(input);

        expect(result).toBe(null);
    });


});
```

When i run it with karma start karma.conf.js i get the error: Module is not defined.

In my karma.conf.js file i have the following files code:

```
files: [
  '../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  '../bower_components/angular-mocks.js',
  '../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  '../scripts/**/*.js',
  '../scripts/filters.js',
  'spec/**/*.js',
  'spec/*.js'
],
```

And the structure of my project is:

```
scripts
--filters.js
test
--spec
----test.js
--karma.conf.js
```

First time trying to unit test something with Jasmine but i don't see the error.

26 03 2017 11:29:10.103:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/Users/user/Desktop/angular/bower_components/angular-mocks.js" does not match any file.
26 03 2017 11:29:10.134:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
26 03 2017 11:29:10.150:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.5.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
26 03 2017 11:29:10.150:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
26 03 2017 11:29:10.181:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the module name.

The module name and the filter name can't be same.

I.e 
 `module('countInputFilter');`

and

`result = $filter('countInputFilter')(input);`

If the module name in `filter.js` is `countInput` and the filtername is `countInputFilter`

Try below code :

```
describe('The countInput filter', function(){
  var $filter;

  beforeEach(function(){
    module('countInput');

    inject(function(_$filter_){
        $filter = _$filter_;
    });
  });

  it('Should not give an output when the length of the input is > 3', function(){

    var input = 'test';

    result = $filter('countInputFilter')(input);

    expect(result).toBe(null);
  });


});
```

Also you `filter.js` should be something like below :

```
angular.module('countInput', [])
  .filter('countInputFilter', function () {
    return function (x) {
        ...
    };
});
```

Can you also share your `filter.js` code.

[Here is the sample jsfiddle link for unit testing filter](http://jsfiddle.net/ehmtksfh/1/)

Comment: The angular-mocks.js warning is fixed and gone now. I replaced the name in the module to countInput (the filter's name is countInputFilter) 
        Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'countInput' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Also share your `filter.js` code

Comment: Thanks very much! I fixed the path to the angular-mocks.js and the name of the module. It works now